# Arithmetic in Go templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I am trying to achieve a very simple thing in a Go template and failing!

The `range` action allows me to iterate through an array along with its zero-based index, as so:

```
{{range $index, $element := .Pages}}
  Number: {{$index}}, Text: {{element}}
{{end}}
```

However, I am trying to output indices that start counting from 1. My first attempt failed:

```
Number: {{$index + 1}}
```

This throws an `illegal number syntax: "+"` error.

I looked into the go-lang official documentation and did not find anything particular regarding the arithmetic operation inside the template.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have to write a custom function to do this.

http://play.golang.org/p/WsSakENaC3

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        // The name "inc" is what the function will be called in the template text.
        "inc": func(i int) int {
            return i + 1
        },
    }

    var strs []string
    strs = append(strs, "test1")
    strs = append(strs, "test2")

    tmpl, err := template.New("test").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(`{{range $index, $element := .}}
  Number: {{inc $index}}, Text:{{$element}}
{{end}}`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, strs)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If you happen to be writing a Go template for use in [`consul-template`](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template), you may find their exposed [arithmetic functions](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/blob/de2ebf4/template_functions.go#L727-L901) useful:

```
Number: {{add $index 1}}
```

Answer (score 10):

Check the documentation about the [built-in functions](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions) of `text/template`:

- `len` can produce an integer from a string: `{{ len "abc" }}`
- `printf` can produce a string of a given length from an integer: `{{ printf "%*s" 3 "" }}`
- `slice` can truncate a string *to* a given length from an integer: `{{ slice "abc" 0 2 }}`
- `slice` can truncate a string *by* a given length from an integer: `{{ slice "abc" 1 }}`

You can combine both to increment an integer:

```
{{ len (printf "a%*s" 3 "") }}
```

will produce:

```
4
```

Or to decrement an integer:

```
{{ len (slice (printf "%*s" 3 "") 1) }}
```

shows:

```
2
```

You can also define templates to reuse pieces of templates.

So we can define 1 argument functions with templates (see [on the Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/DjWvXW9nVMH)):

```
{{ define "inc" }}{{ len (printf "%*s " . "") }}{{ end -}}
{{ define "op" }}{{.}} + 1 = {{ template "inc" . }}{{ end -}}
{{ template "op" 2 }}
{{ template "op" 5 }}
```

shows:

```
2 + 1 = 3
5 + 1 = 6
```

We can go further if the input of the template is an array of integers (`[]int{4, 2, 7}`):

```
{{ define "inc" }}{{ len (printf "%*s " . "") }}{{ end -}}
{{ define "op" }}{{.}} + 1 = {{ template "inc" . }}{{ end -}}
{{- range . -}}
{{ template "op" . }}
{{ end -}}
```

See [full example on the Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/YUV21SiVU79).

Comment: really nice hack for those unable to add a custom function, thank you!

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for this insight! The box I think outside of clearly isn't big enough!

Comment: what if you want to sum 2 numbers? this will only increase by 1

Answer (score 2):

There's also way to just make a HTML list, however that won't fit for all cases.

```html
<ol>
{{range $index, $element := .Pages}}
  <li>Text: {{$element}}</li>
{{end}}
</ol>
```

And it can produce something like that

1. Text: Some page
2. Text: Some different page